# Getting error while connecting to oracle database from sharepoint designer

Tags: database, oracle, sharepoint, connection

I am getting the below error when trying to connect to the Oracle database from the sharepoint designer with below steps.

Data View -> Database Connections -> Create new connection -> configure database connection -> connection string -> click OK -> Click Next.

> "Server Error:An error occured while retrieving the list of Databases
>   from XXX:The server for the data source returned a non-specific error
>   when trying to execute your query.Check the format and content of your
>   query and try again.If the problem persists,contact the server
>   adminstrator."

Answer (score 0):

Following answer will help you to connect to Oracle database from the sharepoint designer

- [Sharepoint 2010 connect to Oracle 11g](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sharepoint2010general/thread/53c9d776-6d68-4456-9e85-a8eeae618b77)